# Ubuntu 12.10 stop updating

Tags: 12.10, updates

I`v been using Ubuntu 12.10 for a while now an never had an issue with updates until recently it just stop updating when i check for updates manually in the software updater it gives me the following error every time:

```
W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/jm.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en  
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can some  please help me??

Answer (score 2):

simple , open your terminal and paste as

```
cd /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo rm -rf jm.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I did as u said an it didnt work this error came up:       Fetched 1,514 kB in 14s (105 kB/s)                                             
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/jm.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en

Comment: @mrpang Have updated my answer.

Comment: yeah I am familiar with the command. I have seen a thread about that while I am in Ubuntu forums. OP said didnt work the usual command. But i made the edit before he said your edit worked for him. so I rolled back whats made him clear with issue. Thank you.